# mysql query error in PHP but working in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I have write a query in mysql and it is running in phpmyadmin, but in PHP it giving me error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select docno, docdate, doctype, narration, drcr, (case when drcr = 'Dr' then amo' at line 2

My Query is in PHP is :

```
$sql = "set @runtot := 0; select docno, docdate, doctype, narration, drcr, (case when drcr = 'Dr'
then amount else 0 end) as debit, (case when drcr = 'Cr' then amount else 0 end) as 
credit, concat(abs((@runtot := @runtot + (case when drcr = 'Dr' then amount else amount*-1  
end))), (case when @runtot < 0 then ' Cr' else ' Dr' end) ) as balance from (select docno,  
docdate, doctype, narration, amount, drcr from ledger where accode = 1 )as q1";
```

what is wrong here with php?

Comment: Are you using `mysql_query`?

Comment: yes the code is mysql_query($sql);

Comment: You can't run multiple statements using one `mysql_query()` call.

Comment: use `mysqli_*` functions, in this you can run multiple queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use transactions to perform several commands in MySQL. 
You create a varible first and then execute another command.

Using just single function `mysqli_query` you can perform only one command and commands are separated by `;`.

When you paste the code into PHPMyAdmin, it will work though as it is still supposed to be a transaction.

You can read more about [transactions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php).